# Bad SQL grammar

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

When executed in java code (db -MS SQL Server)

```
@Test
public void check (){
String sql = "DECLARE @aa int;\n" +
        "EXEC dbo.sc_CheckCode\n" +
        "    @Code = '2002620020210968',\n" +
        "    @Result =  @aa OUT";
try {
    Integer integer = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
    System.out.println("result: " + integer);
 } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("error" + ex.getMessage());
 }
}
```

result:

```
StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [DECLARE @aa int;
EXEC dbo.sc_CheckCode
@Code = '2002620020210968',
@Result =  @aa OUT]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in expression SQL "DECLARE @[*]AA INT;
EXEC DBO.SC_CHECKCODE
@CODE = '2002620020210968',
@RESULT =  @AA OUT"; expected "OR, FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, SYNONYM, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX"
```

Expected Result = 0 or -1

I cannot understand what the syntax error is ...

When I execute in DBeaver - OK (adding `select @aa` to the end from display the result;)

Comment: I'm not sure that the SQL Server JDBC driver supports executing SQL code this way, it is mainly for select/insert/update/delete.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it like "select result from TABLE where CODE = ?". I expect result 0 or -1

Comment: `@aa` should be a (output) parameter declared in your Java and passed to the prepared statement, not declared in the statement. The above won't "return" the value of `@aa` to the application layer as it a variable defined in the scope of the SQL only.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the new line character

```
\n
```

And try again

Comment: no(  result: "PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = Arrays.asList(
            new SqlParameter(Types.String), new SqlOutParameter("aa", Types.Integer));

    Map<String, Object> t = jdbcTemplate.call(new CallableStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
            CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall("{call DBO.SC_CHECKCODE (?, ?)}");
            callableStatement.setString(1, code);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.Integer);
            return callableStatement;
        }
    }, parameters);
```

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/spring-call-stored-procedure.html